# kinect + openni + ubuntu 12.10 installed by apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, kinect, openni, apt-get

I'm trying to find a simple and error-free way to install kinect for my Ubuntu version. Using apt-cache I have an official list of primesense and .... perhaps openni like following:

```
libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev - Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework
libopenni-sensor-primesense0 - Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework
openni-sensor-primesense-bin - Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework
```

so I installed all of them by apt-get install and their versions are 5.1.0.41-2+quantal1. Is this considered an accomplished installation of OpenNI and the drivers?

Or do I need another installation of OpenNI development by downloading at [OpenNI](http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/)? if so, which version of SDK should I install (bcs I saw and also had the problem [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/70585/roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch-no-devices-connected/). Why isn't there an official announcement of compatible versions between drivers and SDK?  (or am I missing something?)

Another issue that I might have soon is that I'm going to install pcl, and there will be a trouble described [here](http://community.openni.org/openni/topics/open_ni_1_x_and_openni_2_in_the_same_machine_problems_with_kinect_drivers). Why such problems cannot be avoided?

I'm novice with Ubuntu and it's package installation

Thank you!

Edit 01:
after installation of OpenNI SDK v1.5:

```
ii  libopenni-sensor-primesense-dev            5.1.0.41-2+quantal1                        amd64        Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework
ii  libopenni-sensor-primesense0               5.1.0.41-2+quantal1                        amd64        Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework
ii  libopenni0                                 1.5.4.0-4+quantal1                         amd64        framework for sensor-based 'Natural Interaction'
ii  openni-sensor-primesense-bin               5.1.0.41-1.1+quantal1                      amd64        Microsoft Kinect sensor modules for the OpenNI framework
ii  openni-utils                               1.5.4.0-4+quantal1                         amd64        debug and test utilities OpenNI framework
```

according to another preceding post [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/70585/roslaunch-openni_launch-opennilaunch-no-devices-connected/), this should be proper already, But I still cannot load my OpenNI samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the Kinect sensor drivers? If you haven't, you need to get it from here: https://github.com/avin2/SensorKinect.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for being here! I think I have installed all primesense libraries in Ubuntu repository list. That is sufficient for the drivers ,isn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openni-dev/Nw8J9WtRTTI), you need the Avin2 sensor drivers for Kinect. The ones provided by OpenNI do not support the Kinect. So if you're using a Kinect, I think you should install the Kinect drivers. Give it a go and see if it works?

Comment: I've tried it already. I downloaded the pre-compiled binaries x64 v5.1.2.1 and still didn't work

Comment: Hmm, try downloading the source and compiling it? I think I remember seeing somewhere that the releases are for Ubuntu 12.04, so re-compiling it may help since you're running 12.10. Also, have you checked out the rollback_usb branch for the openni_camera package?

Comment: I finally installed both PCL and ROS Groovy and the PCL's demos can run already. Currently, I try to publish PCL data and feed it to ROS processing. Thank you!